# How does OSRM "nearest" method work?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, osrm

I want to associate the coordinates and street name returned from the "nearest" method on the [OSRM routing service](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api#service-nearest) with the source [OSM Extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm]). I assume that OSRM create **segments** from all adjacent **nodes** in a **way** and snaps GPS coordinates to the nearest **segment**? Does it create segments by using geodesics between the coordinates of the **nodes**? I ask because I want to find the relevant section of the OSM and add some additional markup to the **segment** returned by OSRM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes OSRM finds the nearest segment by computing the [point-segment distance](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/fefe5e241a7ec62c7ca102f93834308411dfe58c/src/util/coordinate_calculation.cpp#L114-L191) to the input coordinate. To make this scale we keep all segments in a [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).